# More stable reparametrization of a parameter on $(-1,1)$?

Tags: optimization, parameterization, numerics

Suppose that a distribution contains a parameter $\theta \in (-1,1)$. I want to reparametrize this model in terms of $\beta = h(\theta) \in (-\infty,\infty)$.

I am considering:

$$h(\theta) = \mbox{arcTanh}(\theta).$$

Any other suggestions about which reparametrization might be more suitable for numerical analysis? I am planning to calculate maximum likelihood estimates and Hessians, so, having a numerically stable implementation would be good.

Comment: We need more details.  In some circumstances no reparameterization would be needed; in others it helps to write $\theta=\cos(\alpha);$ *etc.* It all depends on the log likelihood function as well as the possible values of $\theta$ you will encounter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "stable" but I guess the Fisher Z transformation like parametrization may work. That is
$\beta = \frac{\ln(1+\theta) – ln(1-\theta)}{2}$

In this case $\beta \in (\infty, \infty)$ for $\theta \in (-1, 1)$.